# Reactjs Send rendered output to wrapping Component

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I've written a component called TocGenerator that automatically produces a table of contents based on the h2 tags in the content passed to it in this.props.children.

**Example:**

```
render(){
   return(
      <TocGenerator>
         <h2>First header</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
         <h2>Second header</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
         <h2>Third header</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
      </TocGenerator>
   );
}
```

**Produces:**

- First header
- Second header
- Third header

  ### First Header

  Some text

  ### Second Header

  Some text

  ### Third Header

  Some text

---

The problem is that if I pass a component which turns markdown into html this doesn't work. The markdown is still converted to html but no table of contents is generated.

**Example:**

```
render(){
   return(
      <TocGenerator>
         <ReactMarkdown source={contentInMarkdownThatWillBecomeHtml} />;
      </TocGenerator>
   );
}
```

I believe this has to do with how Reactjs renders Components and that I've misunderstood the process. I always assumed that the component  in this case would render first and return some html. This html would then be sent to  and become this.props.children, which would be analyzed and in the end generate a table of contents.

Can I somehow make sure  has returned html before it is sent to ? (I can't change ReactMarkdown since it's third party).

Comment: First reaction, this might not be easy or possible (will keep thinking), how about enhancing your `TocGenerator` to also extract headings from Markdown source?

Comment: Perhaps the discussion here gives some hints: https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown/issues/48

Answer (score 1):

So what React passes around are React Components, NOT rendered HTML. What you can do though, is use [`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) to get the rendered HTML from a component. Then you could traverse the output and your code should work normally. Should look something like this:

```
render() {
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(this.props.children);
    // Now do something with html
    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [react-html-parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser) library to parse HTML into React. `ReactMarkdown` might not be the best choice of markdown parser since it doesn't do what you're expecting.

I would recommend using [markdown-it](https://markdown-it.github.io) to produce the HTML and then feed it to `ReactHTMLParser`.

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'
import MarkDownIt from 'markdown-it'

const md = MarkDownIt();

...

render() {
  const { markdownContent } = this.props;
  const html = md(markdownContent)
  return (
    <TocGenerator>{ReactHtmlParser(html)}</TocGenerator>
  }
}
```